# How I can take take the list in model

Tags: razor

I have the 2 modals bellow:

```
public class Search
    {
        public string searchName { get; set; }
        public List<Human> humanList { get; set; }
    }

public class Human
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the controller look like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewList(string Name)
        {

            string searching = "";
            if (Name != null)
            {
                searching = Name;
            }

            List<Human> humanList = new HumanBus().HumanList(searching);

            Search search = new Search();
            search.searchName = searching;
            search.humanList = humanList;

            return View(search);
        }
```

Finally, I declare in .cshtml:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Search
```

I can get searchName easily, but i am still wondering how I can get humanList items to site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below solution to get human list values inside the razor view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.humanList )
{
    <ul>
        @if (item != null)
        {
            <li>
                <div>
                    <label>@item.Id </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>@item.Name </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```